# Cлово "ёрничать"

Tags: этимология

Вообще, насколько я знаю, слова, начинающиеся на Е или Ё, в русском языке редки. Откуда же тогда взялись слова "ёрничать", "ёрник"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Происходит от русск. ёра «задира, забияка, озорник, беспутник».
Из этимологического словаря.